# IBM Containers (Dockers) service in Bluemix start before network service is ready

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I am having a problem in all my Dockers running in IBM Container service. The application (the docker it self, I mean) is started when the service still has not configured the red for that docker. After some seconds (maybe 20 or 30) the docker has full network connectivity. This is generating a lot of problems, as it takes about that time to have both internal and external IP interfaces correctly configured by system.

Currently I am inserting a sleep thread in all my dockers applications so they wait for that time before starting to work but I wonder if there is a way to instruct the host not to start the container until the network is ready.

Thanks

Note: This question is related to IBM Containers service, not generic Docker. That is why I don't specify any Docker version, as it is a CaaS service. Anyway, and to be precise, we run the container service using the cloud foundry extensions, not the docker command:

```
cf ic run --name CONTAINER_NAME -m 512 registry.ng.bluemix.net/MY_ZONE/MY_DOCKER_IMAGE
```

Comment: Whoever marked this down, please provide a reason next time. It's just basic etiquette here.

Comment: icordoba, your question is unclear. Put yourself in the shoes of people reading it here and add code like commands you use, info about your environment (`docker info`, `docker version`) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Alkaline, but I am talking about IBM Containers which is a specific offering of Docker, not really a docker version running locally (in fact we don't use docker command but cloud foundry specific implementation). Anyway, I will clarify this as more people may also understand that I am talking about generic Docker. (I also wonder why someone marked it down... )

Comment: Yes, many people just mark down when they find the question unclear. Let me mark it up to avoid people skipping your question.